# can you help me fix my STS? as it is not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite, sts

I am new to STS and trying to run my first project in it. But it is not showing me run on server option. I have tried "clean install" but still, it is not working. When I checked targeted runtimes it is not showing any server in it. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: also, STS is showing an error "Periodic workspace save" has encountered a problem. Could not write metadata for "/SpringMVCMultipleViewPage".

Answer (score 0):

My recommendations for getting started with the Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse are:

- start the IDE with an empty workspace
- create a new Spring Boot project using the wizard "Import Spring Getting Started Content" to import some getting started guides, for example the Rest Service example
- if you decide to create an empty new Spring project, use the wizard "Spring Starter Project" - it is the direct integration for https://start.spring.io - and go from there

All those options get you started with a Spring Boot project which doesn't need a separate server to run on. Spring Boot comes with am embedded server component, so you can just start the Spring Boot application as a regular Java app. No need to install a local server or use the "Run on Server" option in the IDE.